# Determine the index of a section from the action of a control in a section header in a dynamic tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a TableViewController where both sections and rows can be added or removed at any time. Each sections header is a UITableViewHeaderFooterView where a button has been added.

When a button is touched, how would you determine the index of the section with the touched button?

**Prerequisites**

There is a model object driving the tableview. The model has a property returning an array representing the number of sections. Each object in the array represents a row.

**Requirements**

The implementation must not rely on duplication of state or model information.

Rows and sections will be inserted and removed by tableview animations.
Tableview reloadData will ideally not be called for updates.

Comment: Upon creation of the button/view, set the tag of the button to that of the section. Then read the tag.

Comment: Would that work reliably if a section is animated in after a section is displayed tho?. Say we have section A, and B with tags 0 and 1. If a section C is animated in above A, resulting in sections C, A, B, when would I update the tags of A and B? Can I be certain viewForHeaderInSection is called for all sections?

Comment: Other option is maintain the section views in your datasource, and use the index of the object in the array to determine the section index

Comment: Test confirm that neither viewForHeaderInSection nor willDisplayHeaderView is called for each existing section when a section is animated by [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic].

Answer (score 2):

Define an instance variable `NSMutableArray` of `UIViews` (your section footers). This will act as your datasource for section headers/footers:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *buttonView = [self.sectionArray objectAtIndex:section];
    return buttonView;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.sectionArray count];
}

- (void)didPressSectionButton:(id)sender
{
    int section = [self.sectionArray indexOfObject:sender];
}
```

This is just a basic example, you could use an NSDictionary to power your entire UITableView, for rows and sections. Using KV pairs.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I would how ever not want to add logic to keep the state of an array up to date with my existing model that drives the tableview. I will update my question with additional information about the implementation.

Comment: If you want to be able to find out dynamically what section header has been pressed I see little other option than to modify the datasource that drives the tableview, especially if tags aren't suitable either. Can you not have an Array of dictionaries? Where each dictionary represents a section, and in it, it will contain all the information for each cell (i.e. rowArray) and header/footer view?

Comment: I'm aiming for max code maintainability. Added complexity is expensive.

Comment: This isn't added complexity, this would be part of your existing solution. Any other approach would be added complexity. But hey, up to you, this is my answer, see what else comes up!